# In golang how to test a map or channel is uninitialized

Tags: go

```
var m map[int]int
var c chan int
```

How to test if m and c is uninitialized with make

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the values with `nil` to see if they're initialized. For example:

```
var m map[int]int
var c chan int
fmt.Println("is m uninitialized:", m == nil) // true
fmt.Println("is c uninitialized:", c == nil) // true

m = make(map[int]int)
c = make(chan int)
fmt.Println("is m uninitialized:", m == nil) // false
fmt.Println("is c uninitialized:", c == nil) // false
```

playground example code - https://play.golang.org/p/FzhygumF4v

Answer (score 1):

```
if m == nil || c == nil {
   wtf();
}
```